# count number of highest ratings value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table FixtureStats

```
Id    FixtureId    PlayerID Rating    other Attributes
1       1              1      8.5
2       1              2      6.8
3       1              3      9.1   << man of the match(Motm) 
.....
100     4              1      5.3
101     4              2      7.6     << Motm
102     4              3      4.5
```

I want to select a list of players and the number of Motm one's achieved.

Eg.

```
    PlayerId   Motm

     1          0
     2          1
     3          1
```

Thanks all.

Comment: What determines MOTM? Is it in the Other Attributes field?

Comment: MOTM is the one who has the best rating in one fixture like above. Fixture 1: player 3 has highest rating...

Comment: MOTM seems to be the player that scored highest in a given FixtureId

Comment: Thanks. What's the Id in the result? Is it the FixtureStatsId?

Comment: sorry to confuse you, i just removed the Id from the result. it doesnt' matter.

Comment: ....classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *
                    ,CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FixtureID ORDER BY Rating DESC) = 1 THEN 1 END AS Motm
              FROM FixturStats
             )
SELECT PlayerID
      ,SUM(Motm) AS Motm
FROM cte
GROUP BY PlayerID
```

Since you only care about the `Motm` I wrapped it in `CASE` so it's either `1` or `NULL`, and can then be aggregated simply.  If you wanted to look at how often someone was 2nd place or 3rd, you could remove the `CASE` and aggregate differently.

`ROW_NUMBER()` creates a number for every row in a group determined by `PARTITION BY` and are numbered according to the `ORDER BY`, in this case, you want the top `rating` from each `FixtureID`, so we use those.

Comment: i accepted your answer for coming up with the first idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FixtureId ORDER BY Rating DESC)
    FROM FixtureStats
)
SELECT
    p.PlayerID,
    Motm = COUNT(c.PlayerID)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PlayerID FROM FixtureStats
)p
LEFT JOIN CTE c
    ON c.PlayerID = p.PlayerID
    AND c.rn = 1
GROUP BY p.PlayerID
```